# How to improve testability of a command parser (in a C# Console app)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, windows-console

I have a program using the console as a GUI in C# .NET to parse commands from the user.  It has different commands - some of them must be exact matches like "look", "inventory", or "help".  Others only need to contain a partial word or phrase - any phrase with "north" or "east" will initiate a move that direction in the world.

For example:

```
if(command == "help")
  { << Console.Writeline code to print the help >> }
else if (command.Contains == "inv")
  {  << code using Console.Writeline to print the inventory >> )
else if (command.Contains("north"))
  { << code to move north, then print location info with Console.Writeline >>)
<< etc. >>
```

Since it's a console app, a lot of the action code writes to the console as output. I'm trying to figure out how to unit test this, and my (admittedly beginner) take on it is that I should remove the dependency on the console and use dependency injection to pass the console (or maybe a generic interface to a text stream or something like that?) into this parsing code, so that I can fake the console, but I'm not sure how to do that.

### Question

Is Dependency Injection the right way to proceed here - if so, what's the right path to implement it?

Comment: You need to implement an interface to be able to do DI & IoC. Its a bad idea doing that in a console app or any presentation tier for that matter. The GUI is "bound" to the model. So if you want to use DI you will have to move all your logic to a different project. Take a look at how we do it with WebAPI, scroll down to the `mockRepository.Setup` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: If it's a simple console app, with text output, I think my Console Output to file is a good simple solution. Moving your logic and using DI is a much better architecture. Mocking tests does have a learning curve, do practice the examples. Good luck!

Comment: I understand the question being too broad, adjusting the final questions to be more narrow.  I do appreciate all the answers so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you don't have to write your logic at one place. You can take the advantage of Command Pattern. You will need a class that represents your object's state. Let's call it as CustomObject.

```
public class CustomObject
{
    //properties that represent the state, direction, inventory, etc.
    public string Direction{get;set;}//etc.
}

public interface ICommand
{
    string Execute(CustomObject obj);
}

public class InventoryCommand: ICommand
{
    public string Execute(CustomObject obj)
    {
        //code to create the inventory string from CustomObject
        return "Inventory String";
    }
}

public class NorthCommand: ICommand
{
    public string Execute(CustomObject obj)
    {
        //code to move the object to north
        return "Command Information";
    }
}


//In your test cases, you can do

CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
//test for inventory command
var expectedOutput = "Expected Output";
var result = (new InventoryCommand()).Execute(obj);
Assert.Equal(result, expectedOuput);

//In your console program
if(command == "help")
{  
    Console.Writeline((new HelpCommand()).Execute(obj)); 
}
else if (command.Contains == "inv")
{  
    Console.Writeline((new InventoryCommand()).Execute(obj)); 
)
```

You can further segregate command interface as per the different families of commands you have.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I like the Interface piece, but do you really want a separate class for each command?  Wouldn't those be better as a singleton with separate methods for each command?  Or one class per "family of commands", as you say?  I'm trying to think through how the tests will be built (and the test dummies/fakes).  Maybe I just need to try building it a few different ways and see what I like the best?  :)

Comment: If you create a single class for all commands, you would have to add a new method for any new command in future, and changes in the calling code accordingly. But, if you create different classes for different types of commands(you can introduce parameters in Execute method based on the family of command), you will never need to change your existing code anywhere, or you will need minimal modifications. Rest is totally upto you how you want to structure your code based on the complexity of your business objects.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the [testing pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html) you should:

#### Integration test

Start with integration test box tests where you test in a scripting language, **those are few** and should be exploratory or involving corner cases involving the standard input/output.

```
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo.FileName = ".\mud.exe"
$process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
if ( $process.Start() ) {
    # input
    $process.StandardInput.WriteLine("help");
    $process.StandardInput.WriteLine();
    # output check
    $output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    if ( $output ) {
        if ( $output.Contains("this is a help") ) {
            Write "pass"
        }
        else {
            Write-Error $output
        }
    }
    $process.WaitForExit()
}
```

#### Input

Quickly arrange input validation with some library like [fluent command line parser](https://github.com/fclp/fluent-command-line-parser)

```
[Flags]
enum Commands
{
    Help = 1,
    Inv = 2,
    North = 4
}
var p = new FluentCommandLineParser();
p.Setup<Commands>("c")
 .Callback(c => command= c);
```

#### Output

Inject and compose your output, in this way you will be able to **Unit tests a lot** without too many mocks.
This will mean that all the console writing will be handled by a module that you will easily fake throught the tests suite.

```
IConsoleBuilder { // actual implementation write to console
    RegisterCommand(string command, Func<string[], string> action); 
}

InventoryConsoleBuilder : ConsoleBuilderClient { 
    InventoryConsoleBuilder(IConsoleWriter writer){ _writer = writer; } 

    public override void Show(IInventory inventory) { 
        writer.RegisterCommand(inventoryComposed) ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Giulio.  This helps point me in some useful directions. I especially like the simple, concise description of the testing pyramid at the link.  I am a little confused by the Output section though.  Do you have a link to more details and/or examples, or is there a using statement I can use to find the definition of the ConsoleBuilderClient base class?

Comment: Basically you can create a builder for every business concept you need to output. That object will have the only responsibility to write on the generic output that will depend on the IConsoleWriter injected.
All the things common to many business objects, for example the change of the console colour, can kept the info in the CoinsoleBuilderClient.  
With one mock on IConsoleWriter you will be able to independently test the writing of all the output commands.

Answer (score 1):

> Since it's a console app, a lot of the action code writes to the console as output. I'm trying to figure out how to unit test this

One way is to use a **TraceListener** and log everything out to a file instead of the Console. Typically we use `TextWriterTraceListener` to log `Trace` and `Debug` outputs to a file.

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[TestClass]
public class AssemblyInitUnitTest
{
    static FileStream objStream;

    [AssemblyInitialize()]
    public static void Setup(TestContext testContext)
    {
        objStream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\AAA_UnitTestPerfMonitor.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        TextWriterTraceListener objTraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(objStream);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(objTraceListener);
        Trace.WriteLine("===================================");
        Trace.WriteLine("App Start:" + DateTime.Now);
        Trace.WriteLine("===================================");    
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void TearDown()
    {
        Trace.Flush();
        objStream.Close();
    }
}
```

We can do the same thing for Console, wire it up in the `[AssemblyInitialize()]` like so:

```
ConsoleTraceListener ctl = new ConsoleTraceListener(false);
ctl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime;
Trace.Listeners.Add(ctl);
```

Then you can read the file and `Assert` the actual results equal the expected results.

```
string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\AAA_UnitTestPerfMonitor.txt");
Assert.IsTrue(fileLines[0] == "<< Console.Writeline code to print the help >> ");
```

There will probably be other ways. So hang out a bit to see if anyone else answers.